# How can I get 3 tables INNER JOIN in MS SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

From the specialist table, retrieve the first name, last name and contact number for the people that provide care to penguins from the species table.

There are 3 tables: tbl_specialist, tbl_species, tbl_care

I need help trying to INNER JOIN the tables to display First, Last, And Contact for penguins.

```
SELECT specialist_fname, specialist_lname, specialist_contact
FROM ((tbl_specialist
INNER JOIN tbl_species ON species_care = tbl_species.species_care)
INNER JOIN tbl_care ON care_id = tbl_care.care_id)
WHERE species_name = 'penguin'
;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a bit difficult without seeing the exact schema of the tables, but your syntax for the subquery is a bit off and you need to alias columns that are found in multiple tables in a `JOIN` statment. Try rewriting your SQL like this:

```
SELECT spl.specialist_fname, spl.specialist_lname, spl.specialist_contact
FROM tbl_specialist spl
INNER JOIN tbl_species s
    ON spl.species_care = s.species_care
INNER JOIN tbl_care c
    ON s.care_id = c.care_id
WHERE s.species_name = 'penguin'
```

I'm obviously inferring which tables certain columns come from in the join, but hopefully you get the idea.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out thank you.

```
SELECT specialist_fname, specialist_lname, specialist_contact
FROM ((tbl_specialist
INNER JOIN tbl_care ON tbl_care.care_specialist = tbl_specialist.specialist_id)
INNER JOIN tbl_species ON tbl_species.species_care= tbl_care.care_id)
WHERE species_name = 'penguin'
;
```